# Как правильно читать и писать биты в регистры устройств?

Tags: c

Ячейка памяти находится по адресу. В этой ячейке интересует первый бит. Я определяю структуру

```
struct HWRegister
{
    unsigned char _pad: 6;
    unsigned char bit1: 1;
    unsigned char bit0: 1;
};
```

и использую ее

```
struct HWRegister *hwr = (struct HWRegister *)0x12345678;

hwr.bit1 = 1;
hwr.bit1 = 0;
```

У меня профилактический вопрос: это правильных подход? Нет ли здесь чего-то такого, что сразу не бросается в глаза, а потом приведет к ошибкам?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An implementation may allocate any
> addressable storage unit large enough
> to hold a bit-field. If enough space
> remains, a bit-field that immediately
> follows another bit-field in a
> structure shall be packed into
> adjacent bits of the same unit. If
> insufficient space remains, whether a
> bit-field that does not fit is put
> into the next unit or overlaps
> adjacent units is
> implementation-defined. The order of
> allocation of bit-fields within a unit
> (high-order to low-order or low-order
> to high-order) is
> implementation-defined. The alignment
> of the addressable storage unit is
> unspecified.
>
> стандарт C99, 6.7.2.1, абзац 10

Таким образом, в данном случае ваши поля точно окажутся в пределах одного байта. Другое дело, что размер структуры может быть больше байта, и не определено, будет ли `bit0` старшим или младшим.

Answer (score 2):

> Allocation of bit-fields within a class object
> is implementation-defined. Alignment of bit-fields is implementation-defined.

ISO/IEC 14882:2003, 9.6

Comment: Переводя на человеческий язык это означает, что вы можете пролететь, как фонера над Парижем, если "implementation-defined-компилятор" решит расположить битовые поля в другом порядке или сделать какие-то вырванивания для пущей эффективности :)

Comment: Гхм, мне тут подсказывают, что я выдернул кусок из плюсового стандарта (а кто щас другим пользуется?), а в стандарте C всё несколько иначе. Но суть ответа не изменится: там тоже есть implementation-defined вещи, которые могут всё сломать.

Answer (score 2):

Если идет обращение к регистру именно устройства, то помимо проблем, связанных с упаковкой и выравниванием, нужно помнить, что перед записью бита в регистр, регистр целиком будет прочитан. А в аппаратуре встречаются регистры, биты которых обнуляются после чтения.

Кроме того, регистры устройств могут меняться независимо от выполнения основного тела программы, поэтому нужно добавить модификатор volatile перед объявлением.

```
volatile struct HWRegister *hwr;
```

Comment: Всё намного хуже. Дело в том, что есть случаи, когда некоторые версии компиляторов (особенно свойственно всяким старым кросс-компиляторам) не обрабатывают этот volatile как следовало бы. Поэтому, приходится делать volatile для каждого поля :(

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте использовать макрос GETBIT который принимает число и номер бита, сдвигает его и берет младший бит. и аналогичный макрос SETBIT для задания значения бита. текст макросов предельно прост, приводить его не буду. побочный эффект есть только в макросе SETBIT.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно я чего-то не понял, но мне кажется, что регистр размером в 1 байт
(1 слово или двойное слово) лучше перемещать в/из ОЗУ (РОН, аккумулятор)
за одну машинную команду. А потом манипулировать его битами. Т.е. чем меньше
компилятор знает об структуре объекта, тем лучше. Volatile, думаю, не помешает.